# How to create individual Planner Tasks (in seperate buckets) for each member of a Sharepoint Group with a trigger on Sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, task-list, task-assignment, microsoft-planner

I'd like to create independet "Planner" tasks for each member of my team with a trigger on Sharepoint Site. For example, I create a common task on my Sharepoint Site with a trigger, then desired flow automatically creates standalone "Planner" tasks for each member of group in their dedicated buckets. So in this way I can follow the performance every member of my group easily.

If there is a way to do it please explain it in detail with screeshots.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Group By > Assigned To" option to have tasks be shown in columns based on task assignments, which sort of sounds like what you want? If the trigger creates a task for each assignee in the plan, the separate tasks will show up in the appropriate column.

If you actually want buckets dedicated to people, you should be able to use the Graph API to create buckets: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planner-post-buckets?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http